# Java JSlider.getvalue returns good value to JTextField, wrong to toolTipText

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jslider

I work with NetBeans 7.2.

I have a `JSlider slider_random` in my `JPanel1`, entered the value `100`, minimum `0`, maximum `1000`. I set a `toolTipText` for `slider_random` via properties (custom code):

```
"<html>Range (0-" + String.valueOf(slider_random.getMaximum()) + ")<br>Current: " + String.valueOf(slider_random.getValue())
```

Also placed a `JTextField text_current` and set the text to `100`, This displays the value of `slider_random` when I change it.

I set `stateChanged` event to `slider_random`:

```
private void slider_randomStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
    slider_random.setToolTipText("<html>Range (0-" + String.valueOf(slider_random.getMaximum()) + ")<br>Current: " + String.valueOf(slider_random.getValue()));
    jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(slider_random.getValue()));
}
```

My problem is when I start the program and point to the slider it shows:

> Range (0-1000)
>
> Current: 50

Then move the slider a little, and move back to the original position (meanwhile I can see  changes in `text_current`) all data become correct, and the tooltip says:

> Range (0-1000)
>
> Current: 100

What can cause my problem?

[Here's the screenshot, after I lauched it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX8OR.jpg)

Comment: Any exceptions in the console? Can you post the code?

Comment: @Attila I was able to repro your issue. Will see if i find a solution.

Comment: @Dan No exception was shown, of course with 0 warnings, 0 errors during building.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to repro your issue.

The problem is that jSlider's default value is 50. You modified the value to 100, but this was not reflected in jSlider's setToolTip() method where you access jSlider's value (thru the custom code). It would show the old value of 50.

To correct this, one solution is to create a mouse hover event on the slider, so that when you run your application and hover the mouse pointer over the slider, jToolTip method picks the latest value and shows you the same. It worked for me, so i'm sure it'll work for you.

If i can think of a better solution, i'll post the same.

Comment: It works fine and I was able to do this in 5 seconds. (I can write the the value in tooltiptext like "Current: 100", but if I'd like to change my init value, I have to rewrite the tooltip. But you're solution is perfect.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the listener is added after the value of the slider was already set. You may need to change the order. Or, just to fix the initialization issue you may need to set the tooltip explicitly once you initialize the slider.

As an alternative you can subclass `JSlider` and override `getToolTipText`, for example:

```
JSlider slider = new JSlider() {
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
        return "<html>Range (0-" + String.valueOf(getMaximum()) + ")<br>Current: " + String.valueOf(getValue());
    }
};
```

Here is a short demo:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

public class TestSlider {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestSlider");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JSlider slider = new JSlider() {
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
                return "<html>Range (0-" + String.valueOf(getMaximum())
                        + ")<br>Current: " + String.valueOf(getValue());
            }
        };
        slider.setToolTipText("");

        frame.add(slider);

        ((JComponent) frame.getContentPane()).setBorder(BorderFactory
                .createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way to do this action,is to make a label near to your slider then put an variable like an integer instead of "y" or put the get value instead of "y",& the event which you need for this is Item state change ,so when you move your slider the label will move with the slider & is going to show the value ;)

```
public class Slidebar extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Slidebar frame = new Slidebar();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Slidebar() {
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("SlideBar With Text Move");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 317, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    final JSlider slider = new JSlider();

    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
    slider.setValue(0);
    slider.setBounds(131, 60, 53, 136);
    contentPane.add(slider);

     final JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
    int y = 165;
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(111, 173, 41, 30);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            int y=165;

            lblNewLabel.setBounds(111, y-(slider.getValue())-5, 41, 30);


            lblNewLabel.setText(slider.getValue()+"");

        }
    });






}
```

}